# Why does active_storage:install's migration (v5.2.1) generate invalid MySQL syntax when run?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I've upgraded a Rails 4.x app to v5.2.1.  The upgrade went fine and the app runs well.  However, I've now run rails active_storage:install, which creates a migration to create the tables for ActiveStorage.

The migration is created fine, and looks okay.  However, when running rails db:migrate, I get:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'string NOT NULL, `filename` string NOT NULL, `content_type` string, `metadata` t' at line 1: CREATE TABLE `active_storage_blobs` (`id` integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `key` string NOT NULL, `filename` string NOT NULL, `content_type` string, `metadata` text, `byte_size` bigint NOT NULL, `checksum` string NOT NULL, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX `index_active_storage_blobs_on_key`  (`key`)) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

So apparently, it is translating t.string to "CREATE TABLE  (name string)  <-- "string", and not varchar or something.  Why is that?

When I manually run this CREATE TABLE with varchars instead of 'string', the table is created fine.

Comment: (I am using the mysql2 0.5.2 gem).

Comment: I have not tried this, but [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9855#issuecomment-28874587) should fix it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion.  It *sounds* close, and I am indeed using utf8mb4 encoding, but the problem here is actually different - MySQL is not complaining of index key length.  The problem is the generated *SQL* statement is incorrect, in that it tries to define a (literally) "string" column, instead of a varchar.  I don't understand why t.string in the (Rails-generated!) migration is translated into "string" in the actual SQL and not to varchar, when the migration is run.

Comment: Try running command in the project root

bin/rails activestorage:install
or

rake active_storage:install

Comment: @nourza: As the original question mentions, I have done this.  The migration produced by this action is failing to execute, with the error message provided, because of the "string" data type in the raw SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it: it was caused by a monkey-patch overriding sql_type, that was necessary for utf8mb4 in Rails 4.x to fix the primary key type.  I have removed that initializer, and migrations work now.  Thanks to everyone who spent time thinking about it.